# Is there a way to change the paragraph under your website when you search it?

Tags: html

I have a website, created using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, and when I search it on the internet, there is a text paragraph below the name when you search it up. An example of this is shown in the image here for Facebook. Is it possible to change the text in these boxes, and if so, can you direct me to how to do it or give instructions on how to do it?[image] Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the [meta description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML).  Put something like this within your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<meta name="description" content="Description of your site goes here" />
```